# Retain original image clipping path for new image after Pillow resize & convert

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, photoshop

I have spent a good part of the weekend trying to work out how to retain an existing clipping path from a .jpg image after converting and resizing it though Pillow.

The images have been given a clipping path from Photoshop, loaded to an online repository. Then when needed, downloaded via Python script, resized and converted to "CMYK".

The segment of code is below:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

f = [PATH OF THE IMAGE FILE]

# Grab the image for reformatting
img = Image.open(f)

file_name = (os.path.splitext(f))[0].upper()
file_ext = '.jpg'

# Get original profile
icc_profile = img.info.get("icc_profile")

# Reformat and save image
x_Img = img.resize([3000, 3000]).convert("CMYK")
out_file = f'{file_name}{file_ext}'
x_Img.save(out_file, dpi=(300, 300), icc_profile=icc_profile)
```

I originally discovered that the "image profile" was not retained and I managed to discover adding the below to .save arguments solved this issue.

`icc_profile = img.info.get("icc_profile")`

However the retaining the original image clipping path is proving to be more challenging.
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clipping paths are not a standard jpg file format feature, so I doubt you can do what you want with PIL/Pillow.

Comment: Although some seem to think the jpg file can have clipping paths (because Photoshop allows saving them), it' not part of the standard format. Note Hidenori Inagaki's answer to the Quora question [Can JPEG save a clipping path with an image file?](https://www.quora.com/Can-JPEG-save-a-clipping-path-with-an-image-file). My own research seems to verify that. You may be able to find a third-party Python module that can extract the data which is somehow being saved with the file — or write you own clipping path extractor it you can determine how it's being done.

Comment: Maybe if you shared a JPEG with a clipping path (via Dropbox or Google Drive so it doesn't get stripped) it may be possible to assist. Also, I believe clipping paths can be more universally stored and understood in TIFF files so maybe that is an option for you...

Comment: @martineau Thanks very much for your confirmation, I was also starting to believe this is some wizardry that only Photoshop is able to handle. I will do some more digging into the how/where Photoshop writes this data to the jpg, I originally expected it to be contained in metadata however I didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The requirements are very specific, very long story to explain, however, only jpg is acceptable.